# How to stop xampp mysql server?

Tags: mysql, database

I just installed xampp on my mac os x. When I tried start mysql it displays a message that `mysql is already running on this computer. In order to start mysql stop first mysql`. I tried following ways to stop it but neither of them works.

```
mysqladmin version
sudo /usr/local/mysql/mysql.server stop //mysql.server command not found
mysqladmin -u root -p password shutdown //restarts the server but not shutdown
```

when i use `which mysql` command it shows this path

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

and when I issue `ps aux | grep mysqld` command I get following output

```
zafarsaleem    85209   0.0  0.3  2699804  13204   ??  S     7:51AM   0:00.88        /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin --lower-case-table-names=0 --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
zafarsaleem    85093   0.0  0.0  2435488    924   ??  S     7:51AM   0:00.03 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
zafarsaleem    86693   0.0  0.0  2425480    180 s004  R+    8:30AM   0:00.00 grep mysqld
zafarsaleem    86507   0.0  0.3  2678756  11364   ??  S     8:07AM   0:00.63 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/lib/plugin --max-allowed-packet=32M --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro-2.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid
zafarsaleem    86447   0.0  0.0  2435488    920   ??  S     8:07AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --max_allowed_packet=32M
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

When I issue this command `launchctl list` then I do see mysqld in the list as follows

```
com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync
-           0      com.apple.AddressBook.abd
1201    -   homebrew.mxcl.mysql                    <--
443         -   homebrew.mxcl.mongodb
-           0   com.google.keystone.user.agent
-           0   com.adobe.ARM.df0ab5bbe6f698196fcc21e3c1e66dcb758bd911f4d637272d9d8109
-           0   com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0
45          -   0x7fd1bba073e0.anonymous.loginwindow
-           1   com.apple.launchctl.Aqua
1261    -    0x7fd1bba0c6e0.anonymous.mysqld        <--
 212    -   0x7fd1ba5206d0.anonymous.launchd
 230    -   0x7fd1ba5203d0.anonymous.Terminal
```

Secondly when I tried to issue below command as mentioned by @PunjCoder

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
OUTPUT for above is:
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist"): No    such file or directory
nothing found to unload

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
OUTPUT for above is:
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to unload
```

So what can I do to stop them and how? I am very new to mac os x so don't really know how to resolve this issue. Please help...

Comment: You might want to check out Mamp instead of Xampp, I find it working much easier and better than Xampp.

Answer (score 2):

Your MYSQL instance that is running is here `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld` (the MAMP one) and here `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld` (the one installed using Brew).

Try:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin shutdown
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqladmin shutdown
```

Then start the one you want to start. You also would want to check `Library/LaunchDaemons/` for any launch scripts and use something like

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
```

**Update**: Please list the output of following commands: 
    ls /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql 
    ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql 
    ls ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql

Comment: I followed your instructions. Here is what I did: I first issue `ps aux | grep mysqld`. THEN I execute this command `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqladmin shutdown` but I am getting this error `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqladmin: shutdown failed; error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHUTDOWN privilege(s) for this operation'`.

Comment: Please see my updated post as well

Comment: Please list the output of following commands:

  ls /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql  
  ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql  
  ls ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/ | grep mysql

Answer (score 0):

I always use the activity monitor to quit mysql. I'm not sure why it would show up there and not on the commond line, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I tried that but it is also not exiting from activity monitor.

Comment: It does show up in activity monitor? If it does you should be able to force quit it form there.

Comment: It is there but unfortunately it is keep restarting when I force quit mysql server with another Process ID.

Comment: Take a look a here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697553/1357229 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/100948/1357229

Comment: I already followed them and if you see me updates in my post you will find out.

Answer (score -4):

just restart the .dml file in your account

Comment: How exactly is this done?